# FFMPEG Video Corrupt When Not Perfect Square

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I am writing frames from OpenCV using the following method. These code works totally fine when using a perfectly square resolution like 1000x1000 or 500x500, but when trying to do 1920x1200 or any other rectangular resolution, the written MP4 contains what is seen in the attached image. The MP4 file plays that still frame for the exact number of excepted seconds.

What could possibly be causing this kind of behavior?

- The camera width and height match the output resolution
- What is seen in the attachment is actually a frame from the camera, its just corrupted in the way seen.
- File size matches excpected output roughly

```
process = sp.Popen(shlex.split(f'ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -loglevel error
 -s {fwidth}x{fheight} -pixel_format bgr24 -f rawvideo 
-r {self.fps} -i pipe: -vcodec libx265 -pix_fmt yuv420p 
-crf 24 {filename}'), stdin=sp.PIPE)

for frame in frameList:
    process.stdin.write(frame.tobytes())

# Close and flush stdin
process.stdin.close()

# Wait for sub-process to finish
process.wait()

# Terminate the sub-process
process.terminate()
```

[image]

Attached is the ffprobe log

```
ffprobe version 3.4.8-0ubuntu0.2 Copyright (c) 2007-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.2 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  WARNING: library configuration mismatch
  avcodec     configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.2 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared --enable-version3 --disable-doc --disable-programs --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libtesseract --enable-libvo_amrwbenc
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/var/www/html/students/RH-PITCH_VIDEO.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
  Duration: 00:00:03.13, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 452 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: hevc (Main) (hev1 / 0x31766568), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 1200x1100, 432 kb/s, 160 fps, 160 tbr, 10240 tbn, 160 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
```

Comment: what's `frame.shape`?

Comment: also, the output of `ffprobe output`?

Comment: @kesh frame.shape matches fwidth and fheight. so what ever the input resolution is, frame shape matches. and is that something i need to run on the generated file or in this process?

Comment: so, `(1100,1200,3)`?

Comment: @kesh i attached the ffprobe log, and in this case the resolution is `1100,1200,3` but that was just me testing. normally the shape is `(1200,1920,3)`

Comment: Everything is pointing to row/column reversal. Is `frame` ordered in C (row-first) or Fortran (column-first)? I'd try transposing `np.transpose(frame,(2,1,0))` to see what happens.

Comment: @kesh. let me check. so widthXheight vs heightXwidth?

Comment: Typically (C ordering) `height x row x ncomp` But if Fortran, the whole thing gets reversed I think... so `ncomp x row x height`

Comment: so that actually worked in fixing the corruption but it turned the video sideways lol 
is there a way to do this that doesnt involve a function call to transpose? it seems like that has some pretty considerable performance implications.

Comment: @kesh so that actually worked in fixing the corruption but it turned the video sideways lol s o to avoid any performance issues of the transpose method i just flipped the height and width in ffmpeg. very strange because it followed their documentation originally. If youd like to serialize your thoughts into an answer id love to accept it.

Comment: So, which ordering actually worked? `np.transpose(frame,(2,1,0))`? (I'm putting an answer together but want to be correct here)

Comment: 1,0,2 turned it sideways. but rather than doing the transpose, i just switched the width and height in the ffmpeg arg. Im not quite sure the logic behind what's going on but it definitely works. @kesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The described behavior definitely points to piping the frame data in a wrong order.

Given a (row-)contiguous numpy array (i.e., a C-ordered array), `np.uint8` RGB24/BGR24 frame should be stored so `frame.shape = (height, width, ncomp=3)`. If the ordering is not correct, use `np.transpose` to reorder the array dimensions.

Meanwhile, FFmpeg's size input option is specified as `-s widthxheight`. So first make sure the width and height matches the frame shape.

If your frame dimension is correct, then it is likely that your numpy array is formatted in Fortran order, or column contiguous order. For this representation, the correct shape is `ncomp x width x height`. Sending a `height x width x ncomp` array to the ffmpeg's `stdin` pipe also screws up the image. For this, an easy fix is to use `frame.tobytes('C')` to reorder the bytes.

In any case, it would be the most efficient to fix the dimension issues upstream so `frame` is produced in the correct shape for the FFmpeg.

Comment: very well put. thank you. it is working great now